# How to compile java class with jci?

Tags: java, classloader, apache-commons-jci

somebody I use this:

org.apache.commons.jci.compilers.JavacJavaCompiler

I have a jci class:

```
public void compile() {
    sourceDir = new File("java");
    sources = new String[] { "test/HelloWorld.java" };
    target = new File("result");

    JavacJavaCompilerSettings settings = new JavacJavaCompilerSettings();

    JavacJavaCompiler javacJavaCompiler = new JavacJavaCompiler(settings);

    System.out.println("compile -> " + sources);
    System.out.println("compile -> " + sourceDir);
    System.out.println("compile -> " + target);

    CompilationResult result = javacJavaCompiler.compile(sources,
            new FileResourceReader(sourceDir),
            new FileResourceStore(target));

    for (CompilationProblem cp : result.getErrors()) {
        System.out.println("compile -> " + cp.getStartLine());
        System.out.println("compile -> " + cp.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and my output is:

```
 compile -> 0
 compile -> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error: javac: file not found:     test/HelloWorld.java
 Usage: javac <options> <source files>
 use -help for a list of possible options
```

some idea, ty.

Comment: now, does the file `test/HelloWorld.java` exist inside the `java` directory, relative to your current working directory? Maybe output `System.getProperty("user.dir"), the files should be relative to this.

Comment: yes, the file ´test/HelloWorld.java´ exists inside the ´java´ directory... these is my question... the sources files ares files with path relative(to sourceDir) or an absolute path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is telling you clearly that the compiler cannot find your source file with the pathname that you have supplied.  Two possible causes spring to mind:

- you've supplied the wrong source file pathname, or
- the JVM's "current directory" not the directory that contains the "test" directory used in the source pathname.

Things to try:

- Use an absolute pathname for the source file, just to prove that you can run the compiler.
- Print out the value of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` ... which should match the JVM's current directory.  Based on that, figure out what the relative pathname of the source file *should* be.

Comment: but, i think about.. but my files sources are relative to the "java" folder. i want to know if the sources it must be relative or absolute. then i hopes that, my packages struct begins from test and not begins from java/test

Comment: They can be either relative or absolute.  But if they are relative, they must be relative to the JVM's **current directory** ... whatever that happens to be.  (In your case, it seems like "java" has to be the current directory ... so did you "cd java" before running your app?)

Comment: i understantd.. then, i'll change my question.. how to you configure these parameters.. for to compilation no change the packaging structure?.. my output result is: result/[packages and classes]

Comment: You cannot configure the JVM's current directory so either need to *figure out* what the paths are relative to the (real) current directory, or use absolute pathnames.  Alternatively, use the Java tools APIs to run the compiler instead of the Apache commons APIs.